# How to use latestOfMany on pivot tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two models: `User` and `Role`. They have many to many relationship where `RoleUser` acts as a pivot table.

This is my `RoleUser` model:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
 
class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->using(RoleUser::class);
    }
}
```

How do I get just the latest user using `latestOfMany`? So something like,

```
return $this->hasOne(User::class)->using(RoleUser::class)->latestOfMany();
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether  Laravel supports `ofMany` on many to many relationships. The docs only mention this feature under the one to many relationships. It's generally hard to define this in a many to many relationship in a way that can work with lazy loading when you retrieve multiple `Role` models. It's probably easier to implement for your specific use case via a normal query like e.g. `$role->users()->latest()->first()` but this only works on a single `$role` model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
public function latestUser(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class)->using(RoleUser::class)
        ->latestOfMany('created_at');
}
```

and in controller

```
$latestUser = $role->latestUser;
```